# MySQL: How do I use distinct on a column, and yet still select all the columns?

Tags: mysql

This yields a syntax error:

```
SELECT id, name, body, DISTINCT(sequence) FROM `contents` 
WHERE (`contents`.section_id = 74) 
ORDER BY sequence ASC, revision DESC
```

Hokay, so, In my table, I want to select the record with the most recent revision number based on the sequence number.

So... I can have records like this

```
seq | rev
0 | 2
0 | 1
0 | 0
1 | 1
1 | 0
2 | 3
2 | 1
2 | 0
```

and I'm trying to write a query to return the following

```
   seq | rev
    0 | 2
    1 | 1
    2 | 3
```

note: that I left out all the other columns for the sake of cleanliness of the question.
note2: 
exactly, (sequence, revision) combos are always unique.

Comment: How do you expect a `DISTINCT` query over one column to return the correct set of values for the other columns?  If you have 3 rows that have the same value in the sequence column, but different values in the other 3 columns, which row do you want?

Comment: yeah, it was a mistake, another poster suggested I use max, and that could work great... but I don't know how to get it to return the MAX revision for each sequence. =\

Comment: @TheLindyHop Leaving out the other columns may not be a good idea, because their values may influence which solution suits you best.

Comment: @TheLindyHop, my answer shows how to return the MAX revision for each sequence.

Comment: @GolezTrol, the other columns don't matter, except for validating that Im' getting the correct data. the (sequence, revision) combo is always unique.

Comment: So do you, or do you not, need the values of the other fields? Do you only need the revision number or do you need the values for that revision as well? It does matter a great deal in the answer. If you need just the revision number, you can write `SELECT sequence, max(revision) FROM content WHERE .... GROUP BY sequence`, whereas when you need the other columns as well, you'll need a more complex query as demonstrated below.

Comment: I need all the fields for a record, I tried the query below, but only got one record =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery:

```
SELECT sequence, max(revision) as maxrev FROM contents 
WHERE section_id = 74
GROUP BY sequence
```

will give you a result with the (sequence, revision) pairs that pick out the records you want (as you said a pair of those values is unique in the table). Use an inner join to the original table to pick out the other columns:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.body, c.sequence 
FROM contents as c INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT sequence, max(revision) as maxrev FROM contents
     WHERE section_id = 74 GROUP BY sequence) as p 
    ON (c.sequence = p.sequence AND c.revision = p.maxrev)
WHERE c.section_id = 74
ORDER BY c.sequence
```

Depending on whether the (sequence, revision) pairs are unique across the entire table, or only in a set of records with the same section_id, the WHERE clause in the outer query may be redundant.

Comment: let's say I have another column, section_id, such that the combination of (sequence, revision, and section_id) are guaranteed unique. I would need another subquery. but I'm note sure how to create it.

Comment: Just use the query as written and it should work fine with (sequence, revision, section_id) guaranteed unique. If you want a query to give you similar results for ALL section_id, instead of just a single one, then the subquery is "SELECT section_id, sequence, max(revision) as maxrev FROM contents GROUP BY section_id, sequence". Modify the outer query to also join on section_id, add section_id to the columns to be displayed and the 'order by' clause, and remove the outer query's WHERE clause.

Comment: you sure I can group by with 2 columns? this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/UgxnCGiR gives syntax error with the subquery. EDIT: I had my WHERE clause in the wrong spot. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 3):

This query selects all records where the revision matches the maximum revision for the same sequence, and returns the other fields for the same record too.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.body, c.sequence 
FROM contents c
WHERE 
  c.section_id = 74 AND
  IFNULL(c.revision, -1) = 
    (SELECT
      IFNULL(MAX(cx.revision), -1)
    FROM
      contents cx 
    WHERE
      cx.section_id = 74 AND /* Added this */
      cx.sequence = c.sequence)
ORDER BY sequence
```

Comment: I had an error (a little one) the table name was in capitals in the subselect, which is not good since table names are case sensitive. Fixed this

Comment: this only return one record?  I need it to return all the records where the revision is the highest for each sequence.. just like in the question.

Comment: It does. It returns a record for each unique sequence in section 74. Have you tried it?

Comment: oh, it only returns one record, because I have only one record with the highest revision (2), the other sequences have a revision of 1 or null, but those should also be returned, like in the example in my question =D

Comment: I added a condition in the sub select, to be sure. This is only needed though, if the same sequence can have multiple section_ids. But since the old query didn't seem to work, I think this might have been the problem.

Comment: Hang on, I'm adding some pictures of my actual data.

Comment: Select * of my data set: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Help/StackOverflow/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-13%20at%204.18.34%20PM.png

Your query: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Help/StackOverflow/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-13%20at%204.19.36%20PM.png

Comment: I see! It's because revision is NULL in the other records. The regular `=` operator will not work then. Either fill them with 0 or so, or modify the query.

Comment: I modified the query to use IFNULL. It now treats NULL revisions as if they have the value -1. The query may be faster though, if you remove this, and fill in an actual value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Does GROUP BY and MAX() not work in your case?

```
SELECT 
id,
name, 
body, 
sequence as seq,
MAX(rev) as m_rev
FROM 
`contents` 
WHERE (`contents`.section_id = 74) 
GROUP BY sequence 
ORDER BY sequence ASC, rev DESC
```

Comment: I assume each contains a different revision and therefore the other values may be different too.

Comment: Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html  "However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. "  So in essence, you get random values for id, name and body instead of the values that match the max revision.

Comment: different squence numbers can have the same revision.

Comment: this merges columns with the same sequence number... rather than just select the entire record with the max revision.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this could be used :

```
SELECT id, name, body, sequence FROM contents c 
WHERE section_id = 74 AND revision in ( SELECT MAX(revision) FROM contents WHERE 
sequence=c.sequence) ORDER BY sequence ASC
```